# Error Mounting for ntfs partition in ubuntu 16.04 in terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, command, mount

***hello*.**

i need to help. i want to mounting drive D in ubuntu 16.04.**BUT**
my partition is ntfs format. (Drive C & D)

I had Installed Windows 7 on my computer, but then I Deleted It and Installed Ubuntu 16.04, but i just repartition the drive C. and did not change the drive D partition.

**means that i changed C partitioning and partitioned it for Ubuntu OS(like home & swap & root). partition of D is constant. so D partitions did not change.(D partition is NTFS)**

partitioning for ubuntu in C

When Ubuntu installed, i wanted to open my D drive (ntfs) but get the following error:

[this message show when i want to open drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fycYE.png)

> and when mounting in terminal give me this message:

```
`root@mjb:/home/mjb# mount -t "ntfs" /home
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.`
```

> and this:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda5 /dummy
[sudo] password for mjb: 
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I test this solution:

1. open Terminal
2. type this command `sudo -mount -t ntfs -r /dev/sda5` and then enter

then the partition mounted but i have a new problem:

**the partition is read only** because i type in command -r

ubuntu told me in the error message that: you can mount partition read only.

my question is: does exist any command for mounting partition in the form of read/write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open Disks
2. Select the partition you are not able to mount then turn off automatic mounting options, unselect mount at startup & write `ro` after comma as shown in the image & now you should be able to mount the disk succesfully.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

seems like your windows is locking your HD before shutting down.
  This happens when you try to acess the HD that windows is installed on from another OS, because on shutdown, windows locks the acess to the HD because by doing this, it can gain some performance on resuming Windows the next time you boot it.

So, simply try rebooting your windows before going to linux, if you shutdown Windows and then turn your PC directly into any other SO you wont be able to acess the HD/partition Windows has acess to.

Comment: So what should I do to enable Ubuntu to mount it? Can I fix my problem if I startup Windows live? have any idea?

Comment: Just boot into Windows again and reboot before going to Linux(instead of shutting the computer down then booting into Linux), in case you dont have windows installed anymore check out this link https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwigtrKc4K7XAhWGI5AKHZSoD9YQFggvMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fneosmart.net%2Fwiki%2Fthe-drive-where-windows-is-installed-is-locked%2F&usg=AOvVaw2AcZZuEfmWJvgb8CeJ1-nT

Comment: I turn on the computer with Windows Live and then log off computer(sleep? or restart? or hibernate?). then i turn on it with ubuntu. it's your idea?Did I get it wrong?

Comment: no sleep, no hibernate, not even shut down. The only way it works is if you reboot

Answer (score 0):

Try Shift+shutdown in windows, then boot to Ubuntu os. It will mount all drives